# Re-running my script gives `Access Denied`

Tags: game-engine

I am sorry if this has been asked before. I already searched for a similar question but I could not find anything. I have a piece of code from a tutorial to rotate a cube with a potentiometer. It all works fine until I re-run the script. I run the script it works, I cancel to change some code and when I want to rerun I have to restart the whole program. It gives a `Access Denied` error on my port.

This is really frustrating, especially because I want to be able to edit as I go and test my code. Is there any solution to this? Thank you!

Comment: please post the code or the relevant bits. Try and cut it down to the smallest amount of code that replicates the issue.

Comment: you should also put that tutorial is to follow the idea with more information